# How to extract .inf/.sys install files?

Tags: windows, installation, driver

I have a .inf file that install a .sys file from the windows xp system folder when the user plugs an USB hardware. I would like to trace the files that the windows auto-install on the system, so I can develop an automated installer that doesnt bother the user. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) monitors and displays file system activity on a system in real-time. You could use it.

But Windows wouldn't allow to copy files in `system32` or `drivers` directories. You should use [Driver Install Frameworks API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790272.aspx) to install the driver.